# Custom css font isn't loading

Tags: css, webfonts

here is the page where I want to add custom font http://pgkweb.ru/temp/1/index.html 
So the fonts are:

```
http://pgkweb.ru/temp/1/include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.ttf
http://pgkweb.ru/temp/1/include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.woff
http://pgkweb.ru/temp/1/include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.otf
http://pgkweb.ru/temp/1/include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadPro-Cond.eot
```

And I call them from css (http://pgkweb.ru/temp/1/include/style.css):

```
/*FONTS*/
@font-face {
   font-family: MyriadProCond;
    src: url(include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.ttf); /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
    src: url(include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.woff);
    src: url(include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.otf);
    src: url(include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadPro-Cond.eot);
}   

*, body, p,h3,h4 {
    font-family: 'MyriadProCond', Arial, sans-serif;
    color: #fff;
}
```

But as I see in FireFox code explorer it doesn't works (line-through). But why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your webfonts are inside the "include" folder, as is the stylesheet, i.e. they are both in the same folder, so you have to erase the folder name from the file path in the links, like:

```
src: url("MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.ttf");
```

instead of

```
src: url("include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.ttf");
```

the same with all the other URLs

Comment: OMG, shame on me. Thanks a lot for your observation.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you are missing quotes around each url, the syntax is also a little off:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: MyriadProCond;
    src: url('include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadPro-Cond.eot'); 
    src: url('include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.woff') format('woff'), /* Путь к файлу со шрифтом */
         url('include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.ttf')  format('truetype'),
         url('include/MyriadProCondRegular/MyriadProCondRegular.otf') format('otf'); 
}
```

See here: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/using-font-face/

If this doesn't work, check that the URLs are correct and the fonts are being downloaded (no 404 errors in the network tab).

Comment: Now working even in FF, such a pity that I can't accept 2 answers. Anyway thanks a lot for your help.